# How to show an image under the title in MKAnnotationView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am showing some information in map using MKAnnotationView. I know that in an annotation view I can show title and subtitle and two additional views using the rightCalloutAccessoryView and leftCalloutAccessoryView. But what I want to do is to show some image beneath the title. You may get an idea from the third screenshot in the app in this link: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tripadvisor-hotels-flights/id284876795?mt=8

Any idea how may I implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass MKAnnotationView, add UIImageViews and whatever else, then implement the MKMapView delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

and return instances of your custom MKAnnotationView subclass.

Comment: I can change the MKAnnotationView display image using it's image property. But that's not something I am looking for. I want to customize the callout bubble when you tap the annotation. The bubble can show a title, a subtitle and two customized view on it's left and right. But there is no option for adding customized view beneath the title.